# Arrayformula to return last non-empty cell in multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, trim, substitution, flatten

I need help formulating an arrayformula on how to return the last non-empty cell in a row across multiple rows.

The formula will be in column A in cell A2 and the output will look like this in column A:
[image]

The formula I have is only for 1 row. I need the formula (only 1 formula) to return the last non-empty cells of 1000+ rows.

This is the current formula I have but it's only for 1 row. I need to drag it down every time I add a new row:

```
=LOOKUP(1, ARRAYFORMULA(1/(B2:Z2<>"")),B2:Z2)
```

Is there an arrayformula that can do this across multiple rows without dragging down the formula?

any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 SUBSTITUTE(B2:Z, " ", CHAR(13))),,9^9))), ".* ", ))
```

[image]

Comment: this formula only returned the 3 numbers in Header 10. I needed it to return the last non-empty cell in every row like the output in column A

Comment: @itsover9000 can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZkFDbC08M0dI1qACIC5d-r-uJ0JNRQIgUyu1NPdchGU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @itsover9000 answer updated. try now

Comment: wow it's now working. may I know how the formula works pls? and what 13 and 9^9 does in this part: CHAR(13))),,9^9))), ".* "

Comment: @itsover9000 sure. first, we SUBSTITUTE all spaces with CHAR(13) because you have multiple words per cell. CHAR(13) is an empty symbol that looks like space (but it is not). next, we TRANSPOSE the whole range and use QUERY smash - all cells of each column are compressed into one single cell so we get one single row with all the data. this query smash is possible only if we use the big number - could be any number you wish 9454545, 7876454, 555555555, in this case, we use 9^9.

Comment: @itsover9000 the only requirement is that this big number is larger than the sum of all rows in a given range. next, we FLATTEN our row into a single column and TRIM every cell because what QUERY smash actually does is it takes all cells (including empty ones) and compresses them into single-cell appending a space between each cell. next, we use REGEXREPLACE and remove everything up to the last space so we get the desired output

Comment: Hi. Just a follow-up question. I noticed if the output is composed of multiple words, it's going to output each word in multiple lines in the same cell. For example in this screenshot https://prnt.sc/22tr570 for the "orange fox" output, the word "fox" went to the next line in the same cell.

Comment: @itsover9000  try: `=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(B2:Z, " ", CHAR(13))),,9^9))), ".* ", ), CHAR(13), " "))`

Comment: it's fixed. thank you very much!